# How to toggle a single element coming from a map iteration in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a toggle function to change a property in the state:

```
toggleSelected = () => {
    this.setState({selected:!this.state.selected})
  }
```

I also have a map function to iterate some data:

```
data.allRoomTypes.edges.map( c => 
<TouchableOpacity key={c.node.roomTypeId} onPress={this.toggleSelected}>  
   <Row style={styles.boxWithShadow}>
       <Col style={{marginLeft:160}}>
          <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:"row"}}>
             {this.state.selected === false ? <Image style={styles.center} source={require("../../images/roomtypes/radio_btn_unselected.png")}/> : <Image style={styles.center} source={require("../../images/roomtypes/radio_btn_selected.png")}/>}
           </View>
        </Col>
   </Row>
</TouchableOpacity>
)
```

I wanna that when I click on any row, the toggle will be only worked on that row, other rows will not be changed. But the thing is that when I click on any row, all rows are changed. What are the solutions for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is you are using the same state variable **selected** to track the state of all components in the map.

I would try something like this (I cant test at the moment but i think you will get the idea):

```
toggleSelected = (index) => {
    var selected = this.state.selected
    selected[index] = !selected[index]
    this.setState({selected:selected})
  }

data.allRoomTypes.edges.map( (c, index)  =>
<TouchableOpacity key={c.node.roomTypeId} onPress={(index) => this.toggleSelected(index)}>
   <Row style={styles.boxWithShadow}>
       <Col style={{marginLeft:160}}>
          <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:"row"}}>
             {this.state.selected[index] === false ? <Image style={styles.center} source={require("../../images/roomtypes/radio_btn_unselected.png")}/> : <Image style={styles.center} source={require("../../images/roomtypes/radio_btn_selected.png")}/>}
           </View>
        </Col>
   </Row>
</TouchableOpacity>
)
```

The idea being your selected state is an object {} itself with a key for every index representing the TouchableOpacity elements.

Note: The above code assumes you are initializing the selected object somewhere in your code. Like `selected = {1:False, 2:True...}`

Comment: Solved! Thank you!

Comment: Sure, please accept my answer if you feel this answered your question.